# Using this code will I be able to access on client machine the folder AppData

Tags: c#

If I publish an Asp.Net core application to IIS. And in my controller I have the following action method. Will I be able to access the clients AppData folder.

```
Public async Task<IActionResult>  Downloadd()
  {
    
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

    Return View ();
  }
```

Comment: No, it'll be path of machine which is hosting your application

Comment: @kogonidze That is the answer. You should post it as such. Tappas - good question with a simple answer. I recommend you research whether or not you can get a particular folder on the client machine at all, and then if you need to follow up with a new question. (I'll give you a hint: How would your application handle different client OSes?)

Answer (score 1):

No, it'll be path of machine which is hosting your application.

Depends from your task, if you need to get some files from client (by constant path), one of the possible ways is to configure FTP Server on your server and FTP Client on your client. Then you can create FTP User on server and when necessary, send files from client to server with credentials of FTP User.